# How to Sort Two Data Sets Based on 1 Column Value and Move Non-Matched to Bottom?

Tags: vba, excel-2016

I would like to sort two datasets by the value in a particular column and then compare these datasets. If there is no match between the datasets for a particular entry, I would like this to be moved to the bottom.

So, for example, I would like to sort the following data from column B-E by the value in column B and column G-J by the value in column G:
[image: Initial Data]

I have used the following code to sort the data:

```vb
With Sheets("Sheet1").Sort
    Range("B2").Sort Key1:=Range("B2"), Order1:=xlAscending
    .Apply
End With
```

This leaves me with the following:
[image: Data after sort]

However, I want to compare for matches from left to right after sorting, and would, therefore, like for extra entries that do not have a match to be moved to the bottom. i.e. the entry with the name Dorian in picture 2 would appear at the bottom of the data set, so that Sue, Adam, and Jake are aligned between the two sets of data.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the rows after the initial sort, then do a comparison if true put the iterator in an unused column. After sort the entire dataset by the column with the iterator value then delete the contents of the column.

A rough example:

```
dim iter as long
dim lastrow as long
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    with .Sort
         Range("B2").Sort Key1:=Range("B2"), Order1:=xlAscending
         .Apply
    end with
    lastrow = .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup).row
    for iter = 2 to lastrow
        if .cells(iter, "C") = .cells(iter, "H") then
            .cells(iter, "K").value = iter
        end if
    next
    with .sort
        range(.cells(1, 1), .cells(lastrow, "H").sort Key1:=Range("H"), order1:=xlascending
        .apply
    end with
End With
```

This example is only comparing names on the same line, if you need to compare the entire contents of both ranges you will probably want to use dictionaries to do the comparison.